# d3 tickFormat, remove comma as thousands separator

Tags: d3.js

In a d3 graph, we get comma as thousands separator as default and I would like to remove them and have the x-axis ticks displayed as for example "2 000 000" instead of "2,000,000"

This is what I've tried:

```
    private scaleX: ScaleLinear<number, number>;
    private xAxisComponent: any;

    // Define an x Axis
    const axisNumberFormat: FormatLocaleDefinition = {
        'decimal': '.',
        'thousands': ' ',
        'grouping': [3],
        'currency': ['', ''],
    };
    const axisFormatLocale: FormatLocaleObject = this.d3.formatDefaultLocale(axisNumberFormat);
    this.xAxisComponent = this.d3.axisBottom(this.scaleX).tickFormat(axisFormatLocale);
```

However, the assignment on the last line does not work, it says "*Argument of type 'FormatLocaleObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.*" Any tips? Or am I doing this the wrong way, is there another way to put together a format string to send to the `tickFormat()` method?

Comment: If this is Typescript/Angular/React/Whatever, please add the respective tag.

Answer (score 1):

The last line will work if .format('') is added to axisFormatLocale:

```
this.xAxisComponent = this.d3.axisBottom(this.scaleX).tickFormat(axisFormatLocale.format(''));
```